# FOSUser bundle check_path with localization

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How set login path with user locale? I tried

> check_path:     /{_locale}/login_check

and

```
check_path:     /(en|ru)/login_check
```

but nothing ((

Route config

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
```

Exception:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using
>   form_login in your security firewall configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, i didn't recognized your `prefix:   /{_locale}` under

```
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

You should write route to your action in (for exmpl ofc) `routing.yml`:

```
login_check:
    pattern: /{_locale}/login_check
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:Controller:someaction, _locale: en }
        requirements:
           _locale:  en|ru
```

and in `security.xml`:

```
check_path:  /{_locale}/login_check
```

Don't forget to add

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

in your `app/config/routing.yml` file.

try it, gl.

Comment: FosUserBundle supports this, I've seen it mentioned in the docs, he shouldn't have to write his own security check.

Answer (score 12):

Use routes instead of paths in the firewall configuration:

```
   security:
        firewalls:
            main:
                    form_login:
                        provider: fos_userbundle
                        login_path: fos_user_security_login
                        check_path: fos_user_security_check
                        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

[link to topic in symfony forum](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=42683)